# Voltage Divider for Comparator Threshold

Tags: voltage-divider, comparator

I am trying to understand how the voltage on the negative pin of `U2A` of the below circuit is 1V/2.4V.  From the author: "Threshold signal is 0V/5V but it changes the voltage on the negative pin of the comparator from 2.4V to 1V (approx)."  I have seen multiple blogs that agree with this statement. But the math and simulation show voltage at negative pin as being 1V/3.9V with threshold signal of 0V/5V.

Am I missing something or is the schematic wrong?

[image]

This image shows how I did the math to get:
**1V** when `V1=2.5V, V2=0V` and **3.9V** when `V1=2.5V, V2=5V`

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the quoted sentence means that the voltage is 2.4V if the threshold pin was disconnected? So when it's 0V it moves the voltage from 2.4V to 1V, and when it's 5V it moves the voltage from 2.4V to 3.9V?

Comment: I think you may be right.